# How do i check for mono on runtime

Tags: mono

By default mono doesnt trust any SSL connections. So if running on mono i'd like to give a message rather then throwing an exception.

How do i check if i am running under mono at runtime? (since at compile time the CLI wont know)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll quote from [the Mono site](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical):

> Having code that depends on the underlying runtime is considered to be bad coding style, but sometimes such code is necessary to work around runtime bugs

```
using System; 
class Program {
    static void Main ()
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime");
        if (t != null)
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running with the Mono VM");
        else
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running something else");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just catch the System.Net.WebException and pass your message up? This is approach #1 from the Mono site here: [Using Trusted Roots Respectfully](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully). There are a number of more (and a couple less) involved responses there if you'd like to do more, but catching the exception avoids the coding-to-runtime problem tobsen refers to.